# wifi and 3g iphone and mac app comunication

Tags: iphone, macos, bonjour, 3g

I created two apps, one for iphone and one for mac. They communicate back and forth. The iphone is used as a "remote control" to do things on my mac. For now it just changes the color of a text label on the mac app when I press a button on the iphone app.

As of now, it can only connect through wifi. It uses bonjour and finds discovered servers. What's involved to have them communicate through 3g as well?

Example code?? Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: hi im currently stuck on how to create a mac app, i know how to create an iphone app. although i dont know how to connect them to through the local network wifi. It seems you have been able to do so. Could you please guide me in the right direction. thank you in advance. much appreciated if you want to private message me let me know

Comment: what did you use to create your simple mac app. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you go outside the local network, things get a bit more complicated. It's like any other sort of network routing. You have to know the IP or use a domain name to enable access between the two endpoints. You will need some mechanism that replaces what bonjour is doing that will broadcast to the greater Interwebs. This would require you having a server on the Internet that would facilitate communication between clients and servers. This is known as a PITA. ;-)